# Julia 1.0.0: What does the `=>` operator do?

Tags: julia

I see this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973668/change-values-in-a-data-set-in-julia/50973944#50973944) code for `=>`, but when I search Julia 1.0.0 on-line help for "=>", I get zero hits.

```
replace!(x, 0=>4)  # The last expression is the focus of this question.
```

In the REPL help I get:

```
help?> =>
search: =>

  Pair(x, y)
  x => y
```

> Construct a Pair object with type `Pair{typeof(x), typeof(y)}`. The elements are stored in the fields first and second.
>    They can also be accessed via iteration.
>
> See also: Dict
>
> Examples
>    ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

```
  julia> p = "foo" => 7
  "foo" => 7

  julia> typeof(p)
  Pair{String,Int64}

  julia> p.first
  "foo"

  julia> for x in p
             println(x)
         end
  foo
  7
```

What does `=>` do in `replace!(x, 0=>4)`?  Does it create a pair, a replacement of all zeros by fours, or what?  Why do I seem to not find it in the Julia 1.0.0  on-line docs?

**EDIT**

Code added to help me understand @Bill's helpful answer below:

```
julia> x = [1, 0, 3, 2, 0]
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 0
 3
 2
 0

julia> replace!(x, 0=>4)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 4
 3
 2
 4
```

**Edit 2**

Besides @Bill's accepted answer, I found @Steven's answer helpful as well.  Sorry I could not check them both, but Bill's came in first and they both offered useful information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"What does => do in replace!(x, 0=>4)? Does it create a pair, a replacement of all zeros by fours, or what?"

It creates a Pair. In the function replace, a Pair in the second argument position means the multiple dispatch of replace() chooses a version of the replace function where, given a numeric array or string x, all items within x fitting the first part of the Pair are replaced with an instance of the second part of the Pair.

You can check the REPL docs for replace for details.

Comment: You might check my edit in the OP and see if that works.

Comment: Ah, the type of x matters too. So there is a version of replace for arrays of numbers where there is no syntax error with 0=>4  :)

Comment: Should I edit your answer?  It seems the part about the syntax error could be deleted and then I could accept it.

Comment: Check.  Thanks for updating the answer.

Comment: I really want to find the operator in the documentation, which is excellent all around bit for some reason doesn’t provide definition. The [doc for `pairs` function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.pairs) is helpful

Answer (score 2):

This small example should show how "=>" makes a pair

```
julia> replace("julia", Pair("u", "o"))

"jolia"

julia> replace("julia", "u" => "o")

"jolia"
```

Answer (score -2):

"=>"  operator means "Change into"

so

```
julia> replace("hello world",'l' => 'z')
"hezzo worzd"
```

means Change the string "hello world" using "change" 'l' "into" 'z'
and producing the resultant string "hezzo worzd"

```
julia> replace( [1,2,3,4,5], 3 => 666 )
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
   1
   2
 666
   4
   5
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.  Where do the docs give this "change into" info.  I could not find much in the Julia 1.0.0 documentation?  By the way, those are nice examples.

Comment: There is no "change into" on the docs for Julia. It comes from my experience with Wolfram Mathematica Language. See Rule[a,b] in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, Steve.  I actually used Mathematica years ago, but it has been quite some time now and I don't remember the details.  However, until I found Julia, I would sometimes use Wolfram Alpha for arbitrary precision math.  Now, Julia fits the bill better than I had expected.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The `=>` operator is a function that creates a `Pair`, as described in @Bill's answer. The `replace` function then uses this `Pair` to decide what changes to make to its inputs, but the `=>` itself is completely independent of that, and can be interpreted in completely different ways in other contexts.

Comment: For example, `=>` is also used in the construction of dictionaries: `Dict("A"=>1, "B"=>2)` creates a dictionary with keys "A" and "B", and values 1 and 2. As you can see, `=>` does not denote a transformation here, in contrast to Mathematica, apparently.

Comment: @DNF Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This answer is not correct, as has been stated in the conments here. Its a sort of helpful conceptual explanation, but falls short in trying to generalize this idiom.

Comment: interesting to link julia and mathematica